# MobileFirst paltform: Using Java in JavaScript adapters

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am working on MobileFirst platform for hybrid app development. I am following this tutorial as I want to use my existing java classes for web service call. And It is working fine on Android.

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/using-java-adapters/

Does this works across all platforms. I want to run the same in Windows Phone also.Will this adapter be called on Windows Phone. What is the scope of using Java in JavaScript adapters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapters are sever-side entities. The Java code is executed on the Server and so it does not matter from which client-side application you are calling the adapter from, be it Android or Windows Phone or anything else.